# How to prevent vibration loosening whilst maintaining adjustability?

Tags: vibration, 3d-printing

I have some height-adjustment nuts screwed onto vertical threads to support my print-bed for a 3D printer. They are domed nuts and the aluminium build-plate sits on top of the domes, three holes in the plate align with the domes to hold the plate in place.

How can I protect these nuts from vibration loosening without using thread-locker or similar, so that they remain adjustable?

Answer (score 5):

Double nutting can be an easy option for this.

I was about to describe it myself, but [these folks](http://www.boltscience.com/pages/twonuts.htm) do a great job.

This image, [from the article](http://www.boltscience.com/pages/twonuts.htm), models the forces that do the job.  Take note of the contact surfaces between the threading of the bolt, in the top vs. bottom nut:

[image: force model for double nutting]

Comment: In my situation the stem is pointing upwards and there is a domed nut on the top. I guess this means adding a regular nut underneath it and tightening it upwards against it - but without the other surface (the one with the F2 arrows in the diagram) would it still work?

Comment: I think for your application, as I understand it, the lower nut, which would be tightened against the domed nut, would be referred to as a "jam nut" and should work just fine. 

The double nutting application referred to in the answer above is similar, but the typical application more like a precursor to today's nylon lock nuts or locking washers.